# Symbol ^ in emmet abbreviation is not working correctly (VSCode)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

```
.menu>a*3^+.cart
```

There, symbol **^** isn't working. But in sublime text it's works properly.

I want to get:

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href=""></a>
  <a href=""></a>
</div>
<div class="cart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with the `^` but with your plus `+`.

This produces what you want to get:

```
.menu>a*3^.cart
```